# Formatting a string based on Input and predefined values

Tags: c, string, algorithm, formatting

I have 26 values's that  i am considering as Special Symbol and are as with special delimeter "$" the value's can be from $A to $Z.

Same time i have a predefined template as:

I have $A,$B,$C.....

Now i am allowing user to input a string that can contain a special symbol and the values of those example:
Input - $ACar $BBike $CTruck.

Then my output should be : **I have Car,Bike,Truck... **

As now all special symbol has been replaced by its values.

Note 1.if $A Car $A Bike is the input value then it should take $A as Car rest should be discarted.

If input string doesn't contain any special symbol the there should be no change in output and output will be
I have $A,$B,$C.....

3.if input start as **i am a men $A glass** then till $A all values should be discarted.

Which approach should i follow to make this possible?

I am thinking to do **strstr** on the input string and compare those with my special symbol and store the position of Special Symbol in a list and then as per the position i am thinking to take the values but i don't think it will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing is simplified by using a dynamic string.

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct dstr {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    char *str;
} Dstr;//dynamic string

Dstr *dstr_make(void){
    Dstr *s;
    s = (Dstr*)malloc(sizeof(Dstr));
    s->size = 0;
    s->capacity=16;
    s->str=(char*)realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*(s->capacity += 16));
    return s;
}

void dstr_addchar(Dstr *ds, const char ch){
    ds->str[ds->size] = ch;
    if(++ds->size == ds->capacity)
        ds->str=(char*)realloc(ds->str, sizeof(char)*(ds->capacity += 16));
}

void dstr_addstr(Dstr *ds, const char *s){
    while(*s) dstr_addchar(ds, *s++);
    //dstr_addchar(ds, '\0');
}

void dstr_free(Dstr *ds){
    free(ds->str);
    free(ds);
}

void dic_entry(char *dic[26], const char *source){
    char *p, *backup, ch;

    p = backup = strdup(source);

    for(;NULL!=(p=strtok(p, " \t\n"));p=NULL){
        if(*p == '$' && isupper(ch=*(p+1))){
            if(dic[ch -'A'] == NULL)
                dic[ch -'A'] = strdup(p+2);
        }
    }
    free(backup);
}

void dic_clear(char *dic[26]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<26;++i){
        if(dic[i]){
            free(dic[i]);
            dic[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    const char *template = "I have $A,$B,$C.";
    char *dic[26] = { 0 };
    char buff[1024];
    const char *cp;
    Dstr *ds = dstr_make();

    printf("input special value setting: ");
    fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);
    dic_entry(dic, buff);

    for(cp=template;*cp;++cp){
        if(*cp == '$'){
            char ch;
            if(isupper(ch=*(cp+1)) && dic[ch - 'A']!=NULL){
                dstr_addstr(ds, dic[ch - 'A']);
                ++cp;
            } else {
                dstr_addchar(ds, *cp);
            }
        } else {
            dstr_addchar(ds, *cp);
        }
    }
    dstr_addchar(ds, '\0');
    printf("result:%s\n", ds->str);

    dic_clear(dic);
    dstr_free(ds);
    return 0;
}
/* DEMO
>a
input special value setting: $ACar $BBike $CTruck
result:I have Car,Bike,Truck.

>a
input special value setting: $BBike
result:I have $A,Bike,$C.
*/
```

Comment: the above program's output is different based on the input values.It should output the same as corresponding to the value's.Example - there should be no difference in output when input string is - $ACar $BBike $CPen or $CPen $ACar $BBike.It these two inputs the value of $A,$B,$C is same.

Comment: @Astro It will be the same(it's the same regardless of the order), but also with any problem?

Comment: it should be independent of order.if you give input as **$AAA$ACAR$BBIKE** then the value of $A should be AAA and $B should be Bike **$ACAR** should be discarded. And in the case of **AAA$ACAR$BBIKE** **AAA** should be discarded.

Comment: @Astro i think that the double if you want to enter the corresponding special character Is not it wrong? but it can be changed of course.

Comment: user can input anything even 2,3 or N times but we need to take first value rest should be discarded if special symbol present.Example - 1. **$ACar$ABike$BPen**  value - $A = CAR $B = Pen. 2. **$ACar$BPen$ABike** $A = Car $B = Bike

Comment: @Astro case of `$ACar$BPen$ABike` why `$B = Bike`? not `$B = Pen`?

Comment: Has been modified to enable only the first input.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is called a *Macro Processor* or *Macro Expander*.

You can store your symbol table in an array indexed by the input char.

```
char *symtab[256] = {0};
```

Since the symbol names are single-letters, you can use `strchr` to find the first `'$'` and check if the next char is a letter (`isupper()`).

For the actual replacement, it will require some delicate memory management unless you just use really big buffers and make sure to only feed it small data.

If `symtab['A'] == "Car"` then you can `loc = strstr(line, "$A")`. Then `loc-line` is the length of the *prefix* part, `2` is the length of the symbol name being deleted, `strlen("Car")` is the length of the replacement, and `strlen(loc+2)` is the length of the *suffix* part. So the new string size should be

```
char *result = malloc( (loc-line) - 2 + strlen(symtab['A']) + strlen(loc+2) + 1);
```

Then patching up the new string is

```
strcpy(result,line);
strcpy(result + (loc-line), symtab['A']);
strcpy(result + (loc-line) + strlen(symtab['A']), loc+2);
```

Notice these are `strcpy` *not* `strcat` which appends strings together. The second and third `strcpy` calls overwrite the tail of the string just copied.

Comment: i have an array which will be storing the special symbols as **char ar[26][3] ; which has the values $A,$B.....and in the line i am doing strstr(line,ar(index),,,and then saving the position in a list.But not sure how to gather values?and in your algorithm also how you are taking the actual value of Special Symbols?

Comment: I would index with the regular ascii values, but it does waste space. With your way you have to convert to/from ascii by adding and subtracting `'A'`. For gathering the values, `sscanf` should work. Format something like: `"$%c = %[^$]$%c= %[^$]$%c= %[^$]$%c= %[^$]"`.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you get it?

Comment: I am talking about your algorithm ..from chaking the next charater is $ and next is uppercase ..till what we need to check to take the actual value of symbol?

Comment: Well, if you have something like `char a,b[5],c,d[5],e,f[5];` and then `sscanf(inputline,"$%c = %[^$]$%c= %[^$]$%c = %[^$]$%c = %[^$]", &a, b, &c, d, &e, f);` then you can set the first symbol with `symtab[a]=b;` or `symtab[a]=strdup(b);`.